# Jenkins Pipeline waitUntil bash command returns certain string

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline stage where I wait to get a certain string back from a `sh` script, and only when the strings match, continue to next stage, however, it doesn't work as expected:

```
node('master') {
    stage("wait for bash completion") {
        waitUntil {
            def output = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'cat /tmp/test.txt'
            output == "hello"
        }
    }
    stage("execute after bash completed") {
        echo "the file says hello!!!"
    }
}
```

The execution is something like that:

```
+ cat /tmp/test.txt
[Pipeline] }
Will try again after 0.25 sec
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ cat /tmp/test.txt
[Pipeline] }
Will try again after 0.3 sec
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ cat /tmp/test.txt
[Pipeline] }
Will try again after 0.36 sec
...
(so on and so forth)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [`waitUntil`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#waituntil-wait-for-condition)'s help:

> Runs its body repeatedly until it returns true. If it returns false, waits a while and tries again. --

Your execution output looks exactly like that it is waiting for `output == "hello"` to match. Maybe the content of file `/tmp/test.txt` is not exactly `hello`. You might have some whitespace in it, e.g. new line as the last character.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to add `.trim()` shell stdout to work, ie

```
def output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'cat /tmp/test.txt').trim()
```

Otherwise you end up with output showing a newline character at the end.

but probably, the better solution would be to use groovy script:

```
steps {
    sh "echo something > statusfile" // do something in the shell
    waitUntil(initialRecurrencePeriod: 15000) {
        script {
            def status = readFile(file: "statusfile")
            if ( status =~ "hello") {
                return true
            }else {
                println("no hello yet!")
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```